# How to implement JS from HTML to WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Recently, I'm really interested in building WordPress template. I started doing it, but I am really stuck now. The thing is, i have HTML file of my frontpage (index.html), and the CSS and JS all in their folders. Now, I can't seem to find a way to make the JS work on WordPress platofrm, like its working on HTML.

I only want to make that menu work, don't mind the other bugs.

http://brainstorm.comoj.com/ -- HTML

http://bsarafimov21.byethost16.com/ -- WordPress

Here is the code i want to transfer from HTML to WordPress:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var trigger = $('.hamburger')
            , overlay = $('.overlay')
            , isClosed = false;

        trigger.click(function () {
            hamburger_cross();
        });

        function hamburger_cross() {

            if (isClosed == true) {
                overlay.hide();
                trigger.removeClass('is-open');
                trigger.addClass('is-closed');
                isClosed = false;
            } else {
                overlay.show();
                trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
                trigger.addClass('is-open');
                isClosed = true;
            }
        }

        $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
            $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide relevant code?

Comment: @Jonasw Code added.

Comment: Dude I still see `<script type="text/javascript>` in your page. the `"` is still missing.

Comment: @hemnathmouli check again

Comment: @boka18 firstly try to include custom.css which you already have the referer link and also make script tag available inside html tag. Just check these few fixes, As I can see menu is working but due to white background it is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code working correctly but your html structre different than source.

Add this code between `HEAD` tag.

```
<link id="custom-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://brainstorm.comoj.com/css/custom.css" media="all">
```

Add these lines into `#wrapper` div.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                   v <small>0.0.1</small>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Male <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Male clothes</li>
                <li><a href="male/shirts.html">Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Belts</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Female <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Female clothes</li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Third page</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown heading</li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bank"></i> Page four</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dropbox"></i> Page 5</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i> Last page</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

By the way. You dont need to add `text/script` attribute. Browser defaults `text/script` for script tag and `text/css` for link tag.

Comment: Hmm, take a look now and see what happend pls

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to implement JavaScript via the wordpress function.php. Customize the following script to your own needs.

```
/**
* Enqueue a script with jQuery as a dependency.
*/

function wpdocs_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You have error in `<script>` tag.

Change this line:

```
 <script type="text/javascript>
```

Into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Done. That was a mistake, but didn't fix anything

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in a separate JS file, you can simply call it in the `<head>` of your wordpress:

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The header tag can be found in header.php, in your main folder of your theme. The default location for that file is: wp-content\themes\your-theme\header.php

Hope this helps :)

EDIT: So essentially, you can call it the same as you do with an HTML file. Wordpress PHP has split up your main page template in a header file, a body file, and a footer file. Find the header file, and you can add your script links just like you would in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In you HTML in the WordPress site you have changed the id of your `<div>` from `wraper` to `page-content-wrapper` so to get you JavaScript to work all you need to do is change this:

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
```

to this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

Comment: nice. It moves now, but still not the way it should be. Can u look further and tell me some more info. Really appreciate this!!

Comment: @boka18 it looks ok to me I think all you need to do now is add your `<nav>` from the HTML version and you should be good to go :)